# Making a Bag in Scala with Monoids

Tags: scala

Continuing with [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), the next exercise is:

`implement a bag in Scala`

A bag contains a Map where each of the keys equal the element's value, and the key's value is the # of times it shows up in the Vector.

`bag(Vector("good", "dog", "good"))` = `Map("good"-> 2, "dog" -> 1)`

Consider the `mapMergeMonoid`:

```
// @author - pchiusano
def mapMergeMonoid[K,V](V: Monoid[V]): Monoid[Map[K,V]] =
    new Monoid[Map[K, V]] {
        def zero = Map()
        def op(a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V]) = 
            a.map {
                case (k, v) => (k, V.op(v, b.get(k).getOrElse(V.zero) ))
            }
    }
```

Consider my implementation of `bagWithMonoids`:

```
def bagWithMonoids[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] = {
    val bagMonoid: Monoid[Map[A, Int]] = mapMergeMonoid(intAddition)
    as.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).foldLeft(bagMonoid.zero)
                 ((acc, elem) => acc ++ bagMonoid.op(elem, acc))
}
```

To make this a little bit cleaner, I'd like to replace the `(B, A) => B` part of the foldLeft with `bagMonoid.op`. However, when I do, the result is `Map()`.

I believe this is because using that argument results in `bagMonoid.op(acc, elem)`, which will result in `Map()` since `acc` is an empty Map.

How can I clean up my implementation to make use of `bagMonoid.op` as the foldLeft's second argument?

Answer (score 3):

This implementation of `mapMergeMonoid` is biased towards the first `Map` argument, which basically means that keys that are `b` but not in `a` will never be in the final result. The consequence of this is that your initial accumulator has to have as keys all the elements in the `IndexedSeq`. That's the `as.map(x => x -> 0).toMap` part below:

```
def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] = {
  val bagMonoid: Monoid[Map[A, Int]] = mapMergeMonoid(intAddition)
  as.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).foldLeft(as.map(x => x -> 0).toMap)(bagMonoid.op)
}
```

The `zero` is no longer needed. Unfortunately. I hoped for a more elegant solution, but I don't think it's possible with this implementation of `mapMergeMonoid`. We need one that behaves more like the `union` method of `Set`.

---

Here's a possible (I haven't verified that the monoid laws hold) `mapMergeMonoid` that would allow for a more concise definition of `bag`:

```
def mapMergeMonoid[K,V](V: Monoid[V]): Monoid[Map[K, V]] =
  new Monoid[Map[K, V]] {
    def zero = Map()
    def op(a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V]) = {
      val pairs = a.keySet.union(b.keySet).map {
        k => (k, V.op(a.get(k).getOrElse(V.zero), b.get(k).getOrElse(V.zero)))
      }

      pairs.toMap
    }
  }

// Using foldLeft
def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] = {
  val bagMonoid: Monoid[Map[A, Int]] = mapMergeMonoid(intAddition)
  as.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).foldLeft(bagMonoid.zero)(bagMonoid.op)
}

// Using reduceLeft
def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] = {
  val bagMonoid: Monoid[Map[A, Int]] = mapMergeMonoid2(intAddition)
  as.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).reduceLeft(bagMonoid.op)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my reading `mapMergeMonoid` doesn't actually produce a Monoid at all. To quote from FP in Scala, a monoid must have:

> A value, zero: A that is an identity for that operation. That is, op(x, zero) == x and op(zero, x) == x for any x: A.

but

```
val intAddition: Monoid[Int] = new Monoid[Int] {
  def op(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
  def zero = 0
}

val mergeInts = mapMergeMonoid[String,Int](intAddition)

mergeInts.op(mergeInts.zero, Map ("x" -> 1))
```

produces an empty Map, i.e. op(zero, x) = zero

I ended up with:

```
def mapMergeMonoid[K,V](V: Monoid[V]) =
  new Monoid[Map[K, V]] {
    def zero = Map[K,V]()
    def op(a: Map[K, V], b: Map[K, V]) =
      a.map {
        case (k, v) => (k, V.op(v, b.get(k) getOrElse V.zero))
      } ++ (b -- a.keys)
  }
```

which seems better behaved. You can then just use the foldMap from another exercise to write bag as

```
def bag[A](as: IndexedSeq[A]): Map[A, Int] =
  IndexedSeqFoldable.foldMap(as)(x => Map(x -> 1))(mapMergeMonoid(intAddition))
```